# How to separate loading of assets from main loop in SFML C++ game?

Tags: c++, sfml, code-organization

I'm making a game using SFML in C++. I wanted to separate creation of sprites into a separate function to reduce cluttering in the run function(the function containing the game loop).

I've made a struct called AssetHolder to hold various resources like textures, sounds etc in the form of `std::map<std::string, resource_type>`. Consider the code snippets below.

assetHolder.h

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<map>
#include<string>

struct AssetHolder {
    std::map<std::string, sf::Texture*> textures;
    //Other resources I may add in future.
};
```

menuScene.cpp:

```
#include"menuScene.h"

namespace menuScene {

    std::map<std::string, sf::Sprite> sprites;

    void load(AssetHolder &assets) {
        sprites["background"].setTexture(*assets.textures["menuBackgroundTex"]);
    }

    void render(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        window.clear(sf::Color::Magenta);
        window.draw(sprites["background"]);
        window.display();
    }

    Scene run(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        while(true) {
            sf::Event event;
            while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                    return Scene::Null;
                }
            }
            render(window);
        }
    }
}
```

game.cpp

```
#include"game.h"

namespace game {

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    AssetHolder assets;
    Scene currentScene = Scene::Menu;

    void init() {
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(640, 360), "Platformer");
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);

        sf::Texture menuBackgroundTex;
        menuBackgroundTex.loadFromFile("assets/images/menuBackgroundTex.png");
        menuBackgroundTex.setRepeated(true);
        assets.textures["menuBackgroundTex"] = &menuBackgroundTex;

        menuScene::load(assets);
    }

    void loop() {
        while(window.isOpen()) {
            switch(currentScene) {
                case Scene::Menu: {
                    currentScene = menuScene::run(window);
                    break;
                }
                case Scene::Play: {
                    currentScene = playScene::run(window);
                    break;
                }
                case Scene::Exit: {
                    currentScene = exitScene::run(window);
                    break;
                }
                case Scene::Null: {
                    window.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my main function, I simply call `game::init()` and `game::loop()`.

But when I run this code, it doesn't work. The program doesn't crash. It just displays a white rectangle in place of the sprite. I guess it is due to the fact that when the load function is over, the data is deleted.

How can I do this correctly then?

PS: If you wonder what is Scene and why I am returning it; Scene is an enum denoting the possible scenes/gamestates. The run function in a scene returns the next scene.

Comment: You have to call your load function, just like you do with your render function. Add `load(assets)` before your game loop.

Comment: @OutOfBound I call it in another file: game.cpp. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you're making your scenes namespaces rather than inherited classes? This way you could just add resource loading/destruction to constructors and destructors and also use a common interface to define them.

Comment: @Mario Good point. I didn't think of that. The reason I used namespaces was that quite a lot of answers here recommend using namespaces over 'static' classes. My scenes didn't need multiple instances. So, making classes with static members or using namespaces were the only options. I assumed it must be some sort of a good practice. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: Just because you dont need multiple instances of a class doesn't mean, that all methods should be static. Infact it is most likely a sign, that it should not be.

Defining a class, that only holds members and has only instance is very common, because the ressources of the class can be handled nicely by the constructor and destructor. And if you want to add another instance in your programm, you can just do that without any major change in your codebase.

Comment: @OutOfBound I see. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the game.cpp file I was creating the sf::Texture object on the stack. I created a local variable and was using it's address. So, as soon as the function got over, it took away the data too due to it being on the stack.

I tried using the new keyword to allocate data on the heap & it worked. As the data was allocated on the heap, it remained accessible after the function got over.

PS: A better solution than using the plain new keyword is using it with std::unique_ptr. Unlike a pointer obtained via the new keyword, it doesn't have to be explicitly deleted. So, it prevents accidental memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by *OutOfBound* in the comments, you basically did what you want, you just didn't complete it. :)

Right now your assets are "managed" by a simple map. This is fine, but you'll want some more logic around.

Some quick made up example:

```
class AssetHolder {
public:
    const sf::Texture &getTexture(std::string file) {
        auto a = mTextures.find(file);

        if (a != mTextures.end()) // Exists already
            return &a.second; // Just return it

        // Otherwise load the texture and save it for later
        const sf::Texture &tex = mTextures[file]; // Implicit creation

        // Load the texture
        if(!tex.loadFromFile(file)) // Try to load the texture
            throw "OMG the texture didn't load!"; // This needs proper error handling of course

        return text; // Return the texture
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> mTextures;
}
```

Your `load()` member for your scene could then look like this:

```
void load(AssetHolder &assets) {
    sprites["background"].setTexture(assets.getTexture("assets/images/menuBackgroundTex.png"));
}
```

Optionally you could just pass a string constant for obvious reasons as well.

Finally, when creating your scene, you call the `load()` member once:

```
menuScene::load(assets);
```

This will load all your required assets, while also making sure to not load anything twice (i.e. resources are reused).

Comment: I find your answer really helpful. Can you please tell me why my code isn't working? Or maybe just tell me the area I should focus on(like a hint). I don't want to run into a similar problem again. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @NightMare Didn't really try to track that but white textures usually mean the resource never loaded or got destroyed, e.g. by working with copies by accident. Your best bets would be debugging the program step by step.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I found out my mistake and wrote a separate answer. Still, I learnt from this example. Thank you. :)